# Zooming a 2D game on a mobile device?

Tags: c++, mobile, graphics, rendering

I'm currently developing a 2D mobile game, and I want the camera to be able to pan around and zoom in and out. One method would be to render the entire level to a backbuffer, and simply draw a region and scale it up/down to the device screen. Angry birds has the effect I'm looking for where the user can zoom out and see the whole level.

This would take huge amounts of memory to have a surface for the entire level. Another method would be to scale down each sprite and draw it in the view, but this may take more rendering power than resizing an entire surface.

Another option is similar to the first where I could have a large fixed surface to render the images on instead of having a surface for the whole level. Again, this would take huge amounts of memory especially if the user wanted to zoom out really far.

I've never really developed for mobile before. Would scaling each individual image be too expensive? Should I scale each sprite and then render, or render a large portion of the map to a surface and downscale/upscale that surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to mess with the size of the buffer you're drawing to. What you could do is to adjust the viewport size, thereby fitting more of the world into your viewport (thus ending up on the buffer). Sprites will of course be smaller, and if it becomes to slow for you, you could implement some level of detail (LOD) so that for example "when the viewport is larger, draw the sprite using a smaller, pre-loaded, image". What would still make the solution slow/"inefficient" is that you'll be drawing more sprites, but that's not something you'll get around.